# Unity: Change Colour of Surface according to its angle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, textures, procedural

I made a surface with hills in Unity, on which the player has to travel (like a 3d version of Hill climb racing). How can I colour the parts that go uphill red and the parts than go downhill green? I can't colour it manually since I need to have multiple levels. Thanks!

Comment: Color it based off of the normal?

Comment: I'm hoping you realize that "uphill" and "downhill" are essentially the same thing viewed from different angles. With that said, you probably need to create a shader to do the job based on (surface_normal dot forward) or vertex height.